# Media Player filtering and prepending album plays album, a random song, and then the album again

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a music player and currently I am stuck on filtering and prepending an album to the playlist.

What I am trying to do is play music on shuffle and then when a user taps a button continue playing songs only from the album currently playing, when it is finished I want to know its finished so I can change UI elements and then go on to play any and all music from the library.

However, what happens is it will play the rest of the songs from the album THEN when it has exhausted all the songs from that album will play a random song then after that one random song will go back to that album ..go through its entirety and then play random songs. Once in a blue moon after it finishes the album it will just play random songs.

In a singleton I have

```
func getAllSongs(completion: @escaping (_ songs: [MPMediaItem]?) -> Void) {
MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
  if status == .authorized {
  let query = MPMediaQuery()
  let mediaTypeMusic = MPMediaType.music
  let audioFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: mediaTypeMusic.rawValue, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType, comparisonType: MPMediaPredicateComparison.equalTo)
query.addFilterPredicate(audioFilter)
  let songs = query.items

completion(songs)
} else {
completion(nil)
  }
 }
}


func getSongsWithCurrentAlbumFor(item: MPMediaItem) -> MPMediaQuery {
  let albumFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: item.albumTitle, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle, comparisonType: MPMediaPredicateComparison.equalTo)
  let predicates: Set<MPMediaPropertyPredicate> = [albumFilter]
  let query = MPMediaQuery(filterPredicates: predicates)
query.addFilterPredicate(albumFilter)
return query
 }
```

In my VC to set up the audio I use

```
let mediaPlayer = MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.applicationMusicPlayer


func setUpAudioPlayerAndGetSongsShuffled() {
  try?     AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient)
  try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
  MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: view, animated: true)
  MediaManager.shared.getAllSongs { (songs) in
  guard let theSongs = songs else {
  return
 }

self.newSongs = theSongs.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
return !self.playedSongs.contains(item)
 })

self.mediaPlayer.setQueue(with: MPMediaItemCollection(items: self.newSongs))

  self.mediaPlayer.shuffleMode = .songs
 self.mediaPlayer.repeatMode = .none
 self.mediaPlayer.prepareToPlay(completionHandler: { (error) in
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
}
  })
  }
  }
```

When the user taps the button to continue playing songs only from that album I use

```
if let nowPlaying = mediaPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
let albumQuery = MediaManager.shared.getSongsWithCurrentAlbumFor(item: nowPlaying)
 print("\(albumQuery)")
 let descriptor = MPMusicPlayerMediaItemQueueDescriptor(query: albumQuery)
 mediaPlayer.prepend(descriptor)
  }
```

Upon rereading the documentation I notice it says that I should change to

```
let mediaPlayer = MPMusicPlayerApplicationController. applicationQueuePlayer
```

I cannot figure out how to know when an album has been exhausted and then continue playing the rest of the music library.

it would be great to know if the album does not have any other items so that the user could not press the button to play more from the album

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered my mistakes. I was putting my logic in the wrong place

In my singleton I added

```
func hasPlayedAllSongsFromAlbumFor(song: MPMediaItem) -> Bool {
if let allSongsInAlbum = getSongsWithCurrentAlbumFor(item: song).items {
  return lockedSongsContains(songs: allSongsInAlbum)
}
return true
}


func lockedSongsContains(songs: [MPMediaItem]) -> Bool {
for aSong in songs {
  if !lockedSongs.contains(aSong) {
    return false
  }
}
return true
}
```

I needed to use a Notification

I created a func that has a notification in the ViewDidLoad called songChanged

In the songChanged func I have

```
  if albumIsLocked && MediaManager.shared.hasPlayedAllSongsFromAlbumFor(song: nowPlaying) {
    albumLockButtonTapped(albumLockIconButton)
    MediaManager.shared.lockedSongs.removeAll()
  }
```

On the album lock button I now use

```
if let nowPlaying = mediaPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
  if sender.isSelected {
    sender.isSelected = false
    albumIsLocked = false
    let lockRemovedQuery = MediaManager.shared.removeAlbumLockFor(item: nowPlaying)
    let lockRemovedDescriptor = MPMusicPlayerMediaItemQueueDescriptor(query: lockRemovedQuery)
    mediaPlayer.prepend(lockRemovedDescriptor)
    mediaPlayer.prepareToPlay()
  } else {
    sender.isSelected = true
    albumIsLocked = true
    let albumQuery = MediaManager.shared.getSongsWithCurrentAlbumFor(item: nowPlaying)
    let albumDescriptor = MPMusicPlayerMediaItemQueueDescriptor(query: albumQuery)
    mediaPlayer.prepend(albumDescriptor)
    mediaPlayer.prepareToPlay()
  }
}
```